# Why I can’t erase or cut gradient mesh in Adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, gradient-mesh

Why I can’t erase or cut gradient mesh in Adobe illustrator?

[image]

regards,
Saeed

Answer (score 1):

Because you can't.

That's not how meshes work. Every point of a mesh is connected and interacts with *every* other point on the mesh. Removing a point changes the mesh. One must *shape* the mesh how they need, not randomly erase or cut parts. Illustrator isn't smart enough to reconstruct a mesh, let alone maintain the appearance of a mesh, if something were simply "erased".

Use **masks** if you need to hide part of a mesh.

Comment: Now you can see the image in my post. I want just crop my page but it seems I can’t.
The clipping mask doesn’t let me!is there any way?

Comment: A Clipping mask should work fine. There's no reason a clipping mask *won't* work on a gradient mesh. In fact, that's *exactly* what I have going on [**here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OSI2.png) - a clipping mask shaped like the lake which is applied to a rectangular gradient mesh.  It's kind of difficult to tell what you want to accomplished based upon the mess in that image. Your issue *may* be due to stacking order or some other construction issue. You **can't** use a mesh as a clipping mask, just in case that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: I keep getting this alarm: the selection needs more than one object. But as you can see I have many objects

Comment: I honestly don't know what to tell you. The error messages don't lie. They mean *exactly* what they read. Just because you have many objects, that doesn't mean you are *selecting* more than one object. To create a clipping mask, you need 1 basic shape on top of whatever you want *in* the mask. Then select the basic shape and the other objects and `Object > Clipping Mask > Make`